# Error when starting IPython notebook with Canopy

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I'm getting an error when attempting to start the notebook from Canopy on OS X.  I'm installing from the latest on github.  This also happens with the qtconsole, so I'm thinking it's some weirdness with the zmq.  If I install 1.0 using enpkg, it works as expected.  I've tried installing pyzmq from github as well, linking both as an extension as part of the install and to existing zmq (3.2.3 via MacPorts).  Hopefully, this is fixable.  I've looked all over the web for errors like this, but nothing that I can see pointing to my error, specifically.  Thanks for taking time to check this out.

FWIW, I also have a Python3 virtualenv with the dev branch of ipython installed that too works as expected.

```
(Canopy 64bit) ~ $ ipython notebook
/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend.py:30: UserWarning: The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.
  warn("The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch_new_instance())
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 537, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 310, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 361, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 467, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 399, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 21, in <module>
    from IPython.kernel.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .client import KernelClient
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/client.py", line 38, in <module>
    class KernelClient(LoggingConfigurable, ConnectionFileMixin):
  File "/Users/chris/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/client.py", line 55, in KernelClient
    context = Instance(zmq.Context)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Context'
```

Comment: Could you have a module or package somewhere called `zmq` that's getting imported instead of the real pyzmq package?

Comment: The only zmq is in my User virtualenv.  Just tried this test.  I checked out the rel-1.0.0 tag, ran setup, and tried the notebook - works fine.  Must be something with the 2.0dev branch, I guess.

Comment: The warning about 'frontend' being deprecated suggests that you've got different versions of IPython interfering with one another - you won't see that on a clean installation. I can run `ipython notebook` on the dev branch OK.

Comment: Thanks, I see that too.  I cloned a new local git repo and set it up in anaconda with no issues.  Hmmm, crazy.  If it was interfering, it wasn't obvious where.